Why does Adobe After Effects on macOS keep on crashing on startup?
I have had this problem with Adobe After Effects on macOS almost forever.
The application crashes upon startup with an error message (see below), sometimes upon opening a file, and sometimes while I am in the middle of editing. This has been a problem with most versions since 22.x and also with the latest Beta versions.

I have tried getting online with Adobe Customer Care, went through sessions of Remote help, completely wiped out Adobe Creative Cloud and reinstalled all apps, deleted Preferences, etc., but nothing has helped so far.
The error dump from the latest crash is here. Can help me with this?

Do you have a backup of the computer, meaning everything that you would want to keep if you had to start from scratch with a new computer?

I do. However, the more important part is that I figured out that it's just due to the fact that the latest version of AE is VERY unstable. I went back to version 22, and it's rock-solid...
